# Default values for fields in a new row of a data table

Tags: vba, excel

When you have a data table in Excel, part of the standard functionality is that pressing tab in the last cell adds a new row at the bottom of the table. I want to auto-populate that new row with useful default values. In particular I want to put current date-time in one cell, and copy values into some other cells from the previous row of the table.

It is not workable to do that using formulae -- e.g. using `=now()` for the date-time stamp is inadequate because it will be auto-updated every time the spreadsheet recalculates, whereas I want it to retain the date-time at the moment when the row was added.

So I am trying to write VBA to be triggered by the event of the row being added, and in that code to write values into the cells of the new row. From [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablenewrow.aspx) I thought `DataTable.TableNewRow` would be the appropriate event. But when I try to write any code for that event it is not being executed. When I look up `DataTable` in the VBA object browser the `TableNewRow` event is not listed.

Versions:

- VBA for Applications 7.1
- Excel 2013

So my questions:

1. Is the direction of my thinking right, or can you suggest a better approach?
2. Can you offer any working code that does something like this?
3. Is `DataTable.TableNewRow` the event I should be working with?
4. What do I need to do to get that event accessible in my VBA code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

Write this code in *Thisworkbook*.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ref_tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
End Sub
```

Then below code in a *Worsksheet Object*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo halt
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim tbl_rng As Range
    Set tbl_rng = Me.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    If Not Intersect(Target, tbl_rng) Is Nothing Then
        If tbl_rng.Rows.Count > ref_tbl.Rows.Count Then
            MsgBox "Table increase in size"
            '~~> Do your stuff here
            Set ref_tbl = tbl_rng
        End If
    End If
forward:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
halt:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume forward
End Sub
```

You will also need a *Module* to declare the public variable

```
Public ref_tbl As Range
```

So basically, this will tell you when your table increase in size.
If we're able to capture that, then you can do your stuff when that condition is met.
This works in the situation you describe in your question.
It will not work though when you insert row between entries in the table. Anyways, HTH.

Comment: +1 The WorkSheet_Change event fires when you insert rows, so that might be a way to get at that, if needed.

Comment: I haven't tried your code (sorry) but I don't see how the tables count of rows will ever be greater than its own count of rows. Seems like you'd have to store the row count in a public variable, not the table. I'm probably just missing something.

Comment: @DougGlancy Ah, I store the table range then evaluate the number of rows using *Rows.Count* property. Btw, learned something new. Usually, I use a named range to track inserting of rows or column. *Worksheet_Change* event will make it easier.

Comment: D'oh, I was just reading it wrong. Glad I could offer an idea.

Comment: I tried changing from Worksheet_SelectionChange to Worksheet_Change but it seems that adding a row to the table does not trigger Worksheet_Change.

Comment: @MattClarke What Doug was pointing out is to add another event using *Worksheet_Change* event to handle inserting of rows. The *SelectionChange* stays as is. By above example, I think you can handle doing the *Change* event? Yes? :)

Comment: OK, similar code within two event handlers would work. In my case I think I'll teach the users to only add rows at the bottom so that they stay in sequential time order.

Comment: @MattClarke Exactly. Or disable adding rows entirely :). Btw, glad it helps.

Comment: How do you disable adding rows?